# At what point does a topological space become a geometric one?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, soft-question

A common theme is that there is an "Object/Structure" to which "Maps" are applied; after which invariants can be studied.

In topology, it's topological spaces/structures whose maps are continuous functions (or continuous deformations). Generally my understanding is that, using the topology of the underlying space, we can understand what "continuity" means there, and as such use those maps that are continuous for further study; the simplest case being homeomorphisms which preserve the topology of the structure.

I also understand that metric spaces are special cases of topological ones. Here we introduce a metric function and the notion of distance becomes available. My issue is, at what point do things become more geometric and less topological? One can argue that geometric spaces are built on top of topological ones (but is it always the case?). Sure, geometric spaces can have richer features (inner products/angles, metric/distance, and even measures).

But at what point can we say, this is geometric, uses topology, but isn't purely topology? My thinking is "topology introduces continuity" and "geometry introduces measurement". What scares me with these statements is that there are non-metric geometries (such as projective geometry); is it still considered measuring anything at all? I also understand that there are axiomatic approaches to geometries that might not really follow the "geometric structure + geometric transformations" approach.

In essence, are geometric spaces just richer topological ones? Or are they fundamental in their own right?

Please correct me if in some areas my reasoning is inaccurate or just plain false. I want to learn more delicate ways to look at things. Also, please throw any ideas you have to improve my train of thought, I would like more experienced minds to shed light.

Thank you!

Comment: Fair point, my apologies for bloating it up! I will make edits.

Comment: Compensatory upvote.  I don't think the question is inherently a bad one; it just needs to be tightened up a bit.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be glad to narrow it down with some help. I'm clearly asking a rather ambitious question and I'm not experienced enough to maintain perfect clarity. We're getting there!

Comment: I like this question. It does seem like most geometric spaces have an underlying topological space. Of course, there are things like algebraic spaces/stacks which do not have an obvious associated topological space at first glance (although one can create one), and there are more exotic yet spectra and spectral/derived stacks...

Comment: I think your idea that topology introduces continuity and that geometry introduces measurement is a good intuition, although I'm not sure it completely describes "geometry." I loosely think of a geometry is a sort of "rigidity" that you impose on a topological space, for example, specifying what sort of measurement you allow via inner products/metric/something similar. However, this rigidity extends beyond just measurement -- in algebraic geometry, it comes from the fact that we require our maps to be polynomial maps (well, ring maps, really),

Comment: [continued] and in this case the extra structure is a sheaf of regular functions which one needs to take into account when mapping to or from the object.

Comment: As a first approximation in the spirit of Klein's Erlangen program, geometry starts when you restrict to a proper subgroup of Homeo(X) and study its invariants.  But that is just an approximation, since e.g., we don't typically consider uniform spaces as geometry.

Comment: The algorithm of the site gives these (and more) related questions whose answers might or might not satisfy you: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/192055/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120690/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/322407/96384.